# Django admin, how to keep the query parameters on the next filter

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-admin

I have the following ListFilter:

```
class ProductCountryListFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = _('country')
    parameter_name = 'country'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        unused = request.GET.get('unused', 0)
        _countries = Product.objects.values_list('loc_country_code', flat=True).order_by(
        'loc_country_code').distinct()
        return [(c, countries[c]) for c in _countries]

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        country = request.GET.get('country')

        return queryset if country is None else queryset.filter(
            loc_country_code=country
        )
```

The output in html for this is:

```
<a href="?country=DE">Deutschland</a>
```

I want to add to the href the parameter 'unused', so basically I want this result:

```
<a href="?country=DE&unused=0">Deutschland</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    def choices(self, cl):
        yield {
            'selected': self.value() is None,
            'query_string': cl.get_query_string({}, [self.parameter_name]),
            'display': _('All'),
        }
        for lookup, title in self.lookup_choices:
            yield {
                'selected': self.value() == force_text(lookup),
                'query_string': cl.get_query_string({
                self.parameter_name: lookup,
                }, []),
                'display': title,
            }
```

This method from `SimpleListFilter` is in charge of generating the urls.

This is the html for filters:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/filter.html